# my image loads properly on running on eclipse , but when exporting as jar and opening it there is no image at all

Tags: java, eclipse, image, jar, executable-jar

The image appears when i run the main class in eclipse but doesn't appear when i export as executable jar file. Even when everything works fine.

```
icon =new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("robot.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(150, 150, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
label=new JLabel(icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is no longer a "file" when it's packed into a jar, so loading it this way can not work. You can ask your class for a usable URL for the image's contents using `#getResource()` and use the resulting URL to construct your `ImageIcon`.

Comment: dude i tried doing this it gave me class not found error , the class name here"GUI"  is the class i wrote the code https://pastebin.com/LxFf7MiM

Comment: If your code is in the GUI class, use getClass(). If not, use GUI.class. You don't have to look up one of your own classes using its name, and that might not work if it's not declared in a package.